# Unable to get response when Head method is used with Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: rest, powershell, head

I am running the following within PowerShell with the Head method but I am not getting any response. The expected output is in encoded format.

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://localhost:2375/containers/45e97476b2f5/archive?path=/home/test/' -Method Head
```

When I run the same REST API request with CURL or SOAP UI, I get expected output as below.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-tar
Server: Docker/1.12.3 (linux)
X-Docker-Container-Path-Stat: eyJuYW1lIjoidGVzdCIsInNpemUiOjYsIm1vZGUiOjIxNDc0ODQxNDEsIm10aW1lIjoiMjAxNy0wMy0wN1QyMzoyMToyNC40MD
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Invoke-RestMethod` is for interacting with a Restful web service and as such it does not return the headers of your request even when you specify the `Head` method.

You should instead use `Invoke-WebRequest` which does bring back the headers, and other properties (with headers then being in the `.headers` property).

**For example:**

```
$Web = Invoke-WebRequest -URI 'http://localhost:2375/containers/45e97476b2f5/archive?path=/home/test/' -Method Head
$Web.Headers
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get response using Invoke-WebRequest.